# Where does divisi marking go if vocalists begin a slurred/tied note together, but end it divided?

Tags: engraving, choral

In a vocal piece, the basses sing a B as a section.  Half the basses tie to a second B in the next measure; the other half descend to a low E.  In this divisi writing, bass 1 has a tie and bass 2 has a slur.

Is it more correct to indicate divisi at the beginning of the first note (so that the singers will prepare for it mentally one measure early)?  The two parts are technically different here, as their slurs/ties are different.  Or, is it better to indicate divisi a bar later at the point where they sing two different notes?

To put it graphically, is **a** or **b** correct?

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify for future viewers: "a" wins out *because of the tie*. If there were none, there's no need to start divisi "early."

Comment: The 'divisi' marking is superfluous.

Answer (score 5):

Use version `a` without the *div.* indication.

---

Elaine Gould, in *Behind Bars*, advises as follows:

> **Voice-part division on a single stave**
>
> in rhytnmic unison
>
> A divided voice part should take a single set of stems.... It is assumed, and quite obvious, that a single note is a unison — there is usually no need for double stems....
>
> Some editions prefer to use double stems throughout a passage for an alternating divided and unison voice part ... [or] to confirm that single notes are unison when divisions and unisons alternate in quick succession....
>
> Note that extra down-stems will force text further from the stave. (page 466)

> Division and unison indications (*div.* and *unis.*) should be given only when they are not obvious from the context. (page 467)

Comment: As a singer, I agree—the only reasonable interpretation of the notes is to start in unison and divide, and "div." and "unis." are superfluous in practice.